# Matlab symbolic : calculate expression with vector of symbolic variables

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I need to calculate with Matlab symbolic the following expression :

[image: expression symbolic]

[image]

"l" is a vector of symbolic variables and "C_l" also (same length than "l", that is to say, `l_max -l_min = 3000-10=2990`).

To calculate this, I did :

```
clear
syms l_min l_max fsky Np var1D varO1
l_min = 10
l_max = 3000
l = sym('l_',[1 (l_max - l_min)])
C_l = sym('C_l_',[1 (l_max -l_min)])

% First observable
var1D = symsum(2/((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)
varO1 = var1D/symsum(C_l, l_min, l_max)^2

Error using symengine
Invalid operands.

Error in sym/privBinaryOp (line 1030)
            Csym = mupadmex(op,args{1}.s, args{2}.s, varargin{:});

Error in / (line 373)
        X = privBinaryOp(A, B, 'symobj::mrdivide');

Error in inequality (line 9)
var1D = symsum(2/((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)
```

I don't know to proceed to compute the expression of sigma_o,1^2 just above.

### Update 1

The first variance sigma_{o,1}^2 has been correctly coded. Now, I have difficulties with the second one but I have done some progress in investigation to compute this second variance (sigma_{o,2}^2) :

Now, I did :

```
clear
syms l_min l_max fsky Np var1D var2D varO1 varO2
l_min = 10
l_max = 3000
syms l
%l = sym('l_',[1 (l_max - l_min)])
C_l = sym('C_l_',[1 (l_max -l_min)])

% First observable
var1D = symsum(2/((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)
varO1 = var1D/sum(C_l)^2

% Second observable
var2D = symsum(((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)
varO2 = var2D/symsum((2*l+1)*C_l, l, l_min, l_max)^2
```

But I still get an error at the last line :

```
var2D =

9005901*Np^2*fsky

Error using symengine
Not a square matrix.

Error in sym/privBinaryOp (line 1030)
            Csym = mupadmex(op,args{1}.s, args{2}.s, varargin{:});

Error in ^ (line 330)
        B = privBinaryOp(A, p, 'symobj::mpower');

Error in inequality (line 15)
varO2 = var2D/symsum((2*l+1)*C_l, l, l_min, l_max)^2
```

The issue is that I don't know how to mix the classical "`sum`" function and the "`symsum`" symbolic function because I have the following expression in divider :

```
varO2 = var2D/symsum((2*l+1)*C_l, l, l_min, l_max)^2
```

Is a workaround available here?

### Update 2

`@CrisLuengo` :

Following your suggestion, I tried :

```
clear
syms l_min l_max fsky Np var1D var2D varO1 varO2
l_min = 10
l_max = 15
syms l
%l = sym('l_',[1 (l_max - l_min)])
C_l = sym('C_l_',[1 (l_max -l_min)])
assume(C_l > 0)

% First observable
var1D = symsum(2/((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)
varO1 = var1D/sum(C_l)^2

% Second observable
var2D = symsum(((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)
varO2 = var2D/(symsum(((2*l+1)*C_l), l, l_min, l_max)).^2
```

and get the error :

```
varO1 =

45894056/(97698825*Np^2*fsky*(C_l_1 + C_l_2 + C_l_3 + C_l_4 + C_l_5)^2)


var2D =

156*Np^2*fsky

Error using symengine
Invalid operands.

Error in sym/privBinaryOp (line 1030)
            Csym = mupadmex(op,args{1}.s, args{2}.s, varargin{:});

Error in / (line 373)
        X = privBinaryOp(A, B, 'symobj::mrdivide');

Error in inequality (line 16)
varO2 = var2D/(symsum(((2*l+1)*C_l), l, l_min, l_max)).^2
```

I just want to express symbolically the following quantity (I have a set of data of couples (l, C_l), that is to say, I have for each "l" value an associated "C_l" value.

[image: second observable]

Where might the error come from ?

### Update 3

There may be a confusion about the expression of second quantity above. I have i=1:N couples of values (l_i, C_l_i), and the quantity appears like this :

[image: expand expression]

Unfortunately, when I am doing :

```
% Second observable
var2D = symsum(((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)
varO2 = var2D./(sum(symsum(((2*l+1).*C_l), l, l_min, l_max))).^2
```

I get on terminal Matlab :

[image: screen capture]

As you can see, I have the factor `156` which appears for each C_l and this is wrong **since I would like to have as real values the factor** `(2*l+1)` for each C_l : computation of `(2*l+1)` must be done with a real value, not as symbolic coefficients.

### Update 4

I have badly expressed my issue : with the solution suggested in answer by `@drakon101`, I have always the same weighting values.

What I would like to get is the following symbolic expression for the divider :

[image: different values for weighting : 2*l+1]

How to make change the variable "l" to make it replaced by real values
(3, then 5, 7, ...., 5999) ?

Comment: Some combination of `.*` versus `*` and `.^` versus `^`

Comment: In your second error, you are trying to compute the matrix power of a non-square matrix. Instead use `.^` for element-wise power.

Comment: @CrisLuengo . Could you take a look please at **UPDATE 2** following your suggestion. Best regards

Comment: As @talonmies pointed out 19 hours ago, you need to use element-wise operations, not matrix operations. `(2*l+1)*C_l` is a matrix multiplication, you need to use an element-wise multiplication. Likewise, the division should be element-wise as well. Your equations don't use any matrix operations at all, you shouldn't be using any `*`, `/` or `^` operators in MATLAB, only `.*`, `./` and `.^`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo . As you can see above, I have followed your suggestions by using .`*` , `./` and `.^` but the result is still not the expected one. The issue is mainly about the coefficient (2*l+1) which are all equal. Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what output you're looking for, but according to the equations you have displayed above, your second observable lines should be:

```
% Second observable
var2D = 2*symsum(((2*l+1)), l, l_min, l_max)./(fsky.*Np.^2)
varO2 = var2D./(symsum(((2.*l+1).*C_l), l, l_min, l_max)).^2
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution in behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

I have found the following solution by coding :

```
clc
clear all
syms fsky Np l

l_min = 10
l_max = 15
C_l = sym('C_l_',[1 (l_max)]);
assume(C_l > 0);

% Second observable
var2D = symsum(((2*l+1)*fsky*Np^2), l, l_min, l_max)

below=0;
for l=l_min:l_max
   below= below + (2*l+1)*C_l(l);
end

varO2= var2D/(below)^2
```

Comment: For posterity: This solution does seem to yield something closer to what OP was looking for after considering @stefan clarifying comment. However, it seems like it gives different coefficients in the denominator. However, OP should be able to play around with this approach until they get the coefficients they asked for!